# Angular momentum of a rotating black hole

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum

Is there an upper limit to the angular momentum of a rotating (Kerr) black hole?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the angular momentum is bounded above by the mass squared in natural units (G=c=1), and when the angular momentum is equal to the mass squared, you have an extremal Kerr black hole. You can read more in this [quick review](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eftaylor.com%2Fpub%2FSpinNEW.pdf&ei=ObI5UI-BCqbp0gHE44CYBg&usg=AFQjCNH3yzCarGpP6Fwl95FlONcnbwlbhA&sig2=DfwVlI2W9Z3oiOuokZVMAw) .